# Summary of column in datatable (from package DT)

Tags: javascript, r, datatable, dt

Is there a possibility to add summary to R version of datatable (provided by DT package), like in this example?

https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add a footer to your datatable (using the *container* parameter), and then insert the javascript code you linked in the **footerCallback** function (within the *options* parameter of the datatable).

Here is an example with USArrests datasets:

```
sketch <- htmltools::withTags(table(
  tableHeader(c('State', names(USArrests))),
  tableFooter(rep('', 5))
))

#here is a copy of the javascript you had link
opts <- list( 
    footerCallback = JS("function( row, data, start, end, display ) {",
        "var api = this.api(), data;",
        "var intVal = function ( i ) {",
          "return typeof i === 'string' ?",
            "i.replace(/[\\$,]/g, '')*1 :typeof i === 'number' ?",
            "i : 0;};",
        "total = api",
          ".column( 3 )",
          ".data()",
          ".reduce( function (a, b) {",
            " return intVal(a) + intVal(b);",
        " }, 0 );",
        "$( api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html('('+ total +' total)');",
        "}"))

datatable(USArrests, container = sketch, options = opts)
```

[image]